# Have an element stay in the ending animation spot after ":hover"?

Tags: html

Whenever I hover on the first image, it moves to a different location. That is supposed to happen. But it comes back to it's original spot after un-hover. I need it to stay in the end location. If you understood that, can you help? Thanks in advance.`

I tried to have the code animation infinite, but that doesn't seem to work.

```html
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <head>
  <script>
   window.start();
   function start(){
    alert("This site is secure with SITELOCK TM. If this Website is hacked, the record will be loggled, and will be reported.");
    console.log("This site is secure with SITELOCK TM. If this Website is hacked, the record will be loggled, and will be reported.")
   }
  </script>
  <style>
   @keyframes slide{
    0%{
     width: 50px;
     
    }
    100%{
     width: 300px;
    }
   }
   @keyframes fly{
    0%{
     top: 25;
     left: 17;
     width: 20;
    }
    100%{
     top: 157;
     left: 30;
    }
   }
   @keyframes fade{
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
   }
   @keyframes fade2{
    from{opacity: 0;}
    to{opacity: 1;}
   }
   @keyframes goaway{
    0%{
     opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
     opacity: 0;
    }
   }
   
   .nav:hover{
    animation: slide 2s forwards;
   }
   .nav:hover > center > #home{
    animation: fade2 2s forwards;
   }
   .nav:hover > center > #about{
    animation: fade 2s forwards;
   }
   .nav:hover > #rocket{
    animation: fly 2s forwards;
   }
   .nav:hover > #title{
    animation: fade 7s forwards;
   }
   .nav:hover > center > #shop{
    animation: fade 3s forwards;
   }
   .nav:hover > #menu_mark{
    animation: goaway 1s forwards;
   }
   #image1:hover{
    animation: move1 0.5s infinite;
   }
   @keyframes move1{
    0%{
     width: 160px;
     top: 70px;
     left: 200px;
    }
    50%{
     width: 180px;
     top: 50px;
     left: 400px;
    }
    100%{
     width: 200px;
     top: 30px;
     left: 600px;
    }
   }
   #image1:hover ~ #image2{
    animation: move2 0.5s infinite;
   }
   @keyframes move2{
    0%{
     left: 400px;
     width: 180px;
     top: 50px;
    }
    50%{
     left: 600px;
     width: 200px;
     top: 30px;
    }
    100%{
     width: 180px;
     top: 50px;
     left: 820px;
    }
   }
   #image1: ~ #image3{
    
   }
   #image1:hover ~ #image4{
    
   }
   #image1:hover ~ #image5{
    
   }
  </style>
  <script>
   
  </script>
 </head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Thasadith" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <body style=" align-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #404040; overflow-y: hidden;">
  <div class="elements">
   <img src="Image%201.png" id="image1" style="width: 160px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 220px; border-radius: 10px;">
   <img src="Image%202.png" id="image2" style="width: 180px; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 400px; border-radius: 10px;">
   <img src="Image%203.png" id="image3" style="width: 200px; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 600px; border-radius: 10px;">
   <img src="Image%204.png" id="image4" style="width: 180px; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 820px; border-radius: 10px;">
   <img src="Image%205.png" id="image5" style="width: 160px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 1015px; border-radius: 10px;">
  </div>
  <div class="nav" style="background-color: #282829; height: 800px; width: 50px; box-shadow: 10px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); margin-bottom: 10px; position: sticky; float: left;" >
   <span id="title" style="display: inline-block; font-family: Thasadith; color: white; font-size: 40px; position: absolute; top: 150; left: 60px; opacity: 0;">MONOSPACE</span>
   <center><span id="home" style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 25px; font-family: Fjalla One; color: white; font-size: 20px; padding-top: 250px; opacity: 0;">HOME</span><br>
   <span id="about" style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 25px; font-family: Fjalla One; color: white; font-size: 20px; opacity: 0;">ABOUT</span><br>
   <span id="shop" style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 25px; font-family: Fjalla One; color: white; font-size: 20px; opacity: 0;">SHOP</span><br></center>
   <img id="menu_mark" src="LogoMakr_6Pr2go.png" style="width: 25px; position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 12.5px;">
   <img id="rocket" src="LogoMakr_9Pl0y8.png" style="color: white; position: absolute; top: 25; left: 17; width: 20;">
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You see how it kind of glitches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things. Firstly use `forwards` in the animation rather than `infinite` which is going to infinitely loop your animation. Secondly you need to maintain state. As soon as you mouse away that end state of the animation is lost and will repeat on re-hover. To avoid this use javascript to add a class on hover, this will handle the state for you.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("image1");

const onHover = (e) => {
  event.target.classList.add("hovered");
  console.log('image hovered');
  event.target.removeEventListener("mouseenter", onHover) 
};

image.addEventListener("mouseenter", onHover)
```

```css
#image1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue
}

#image1.hovered {
  animation: move1 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes move1{
  0%{
    width: 160px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 200px;
  }
  50%{
    width: 180px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 400px;
  }
  100%{
    width: 200px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="image1">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timing for your animation:

```
.nav:hover > center > #home{ animation: fade2 2s ease-in-out forwards; }
```

I never use to/from, I always use 0%/100% you can do more things in that way.

Tell me if it works because I use my keyframes like this.

Comment: No, i'm sorry but that doesn't work. I'm trying to keep it in its animation destination, but whenever I move it comes right back to it's original spot. Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: I was thinking `position: inherit;` but i'm not sure that will work

Comment: Yep nope. Whenever I hold my cursor, it goes forever.

Comment: Yeah, hover it just works when you hold the cursor above an element, if you want to set a permanent effect, you must use an <a> with :focus. I have my own style API and I have a lot of tricks there.